# Is it safe to replace hardware while a PC is suspended to RAM?

Tags: linux, suspend

Is it safe to replace hardware while a PC is suspended to RAM?

Specifically:

- Can you unplug an external hard disk without losing data?
- Can you replace components like a drive or a PCI-express card? (I don't know why one would require this, but I'm curious)

I'm especially interested in Linux, but I don't know if the OS matters.

Comment: Really, don't. No benefit, high risks

Answer (score 6):

> Is it safe to replace hardware while a PC is suspended to RAM?

No, as [Toryan already wrote in their answer](https://superuser.com/a/692569/167207), a PC in sleep mode is still powered on.

> Specifically:
> Can you unplug an external hard disk without losing data?

If the OS flushed the disk cache prior to dropping to sleep mode: Probably yes.
If is was not done and you still are halfway though a change on the disk: No.

> Can you replace components like a drive or a PCI-express card?

Replacing a PCI-e card on a powered-on consumer motherboard is a really bad idea. Even ignoring the risk of shorting things when plugging and unplugging cards on a powered on computer, you also run into initialisation problems. Normally a computer boots, detects hardware and configures it for usage. When the OS is already booted then the all devices are already configured. Adding new hardware will require this new device to catch up.

This is possible, but your OS needs to support it. (e.g. this is why you can plug in express-card, thunderbolt or USB devices). I have serious doubt about comsumer OS's and support for adding, let alone *removing* PCI-e cards.

SATA and SCSI drives are an exception to this. SCSI support hotplugging. As does SATA in AHCI mode (AHCI is normal SATA mode, as opposed to ancient IDE emulation mode).

> (I don't know why one would require this, but I'm curious)

For disks the answer is easy. A failed drive can be replaced without bringing the server down. This works perfectly in combination with RAID.  For SoHO tasks: Just power it down.

> I'm especially interested in Linux, but I don't know if the OS matters.

The OS matter because it needs support to actually use the new devices.  Or support to remove them. Which is something you would need to do before sleep mode. (Much akin to how you need to use safe removal for USB pen drives before unplugging them). If your PC is already in sleep mode then you are to late for this.

Comment: "If the OS flushed the disk cache prior to dropping to sleep mode: Probably yes." And do they do that?

Comment: I assume they do, but it will depend on the OS. For the Open source ones we can check it, for windows it will stay a guess. (A safe guess since going somewhat slower into sleep mode is a lot safer than getting corrupted filesystems, but still a guess).

Answer (score 5):

No, it's a really bad idea to start fiddling around inside the case while the PC is still powered on (which it is when in sleep mode). At best, the PC will fail to wake from sleep, at worst you can actually damage the components you're replacing.

A specific exception to this is in the case of hot-swappable components in servers, such as hard drives, PSUs, etc.

(You can of course still connect/disconnect anything that you normally would while the PC is powered on, such as USB devices. Just take the same level of care as you would during normal operation).

Comment: It's a bad idea to fiddle with the insides of pc's with the power on anyway.  You could easily drop a screw into the case and short something out accidentally.

Answer (score 4):

Note: Answering specifically for PCIe devices

*Theoretically*, it should be possible to safely replace PCIe devices while suspended (S3 sleep or deeper), even on motherboards that aren't designed for PCIe hotplug. Assuming you unload any drivers using the devices beforehand, so they're not surprised by a missing device, and your OS is correctly configured for PCIe hotplug.

The PCIe standard defines various power states for the PCIe device, of which the powered-off state is the D3<sub>cold</sub> state:

> **5.3.1.4.2. D3<sub>cold</sub> State**
>
> A Function transitions to the D3<sub>cold</sub> state when its main power is removed.  A power-on sequence with its associated
> cold reset transitions a Function from the D3<sub>cold</sub> state to the
> D0<sub>uninititialized</sub> state.  At this point, software must perform a full
> initialization of the Function in order to re-establish all functional
> context, completing the restoration of the Function to its
> D0<sub>active</sub> state.

(Note that this doesn't include trickle power for PCIe-triggered wakeup events, like Wake-on-LAN. But even a "normally" S4/S5 powered off system will have this trickle power still available)

While a S4 "hibernate" or S5 "soft off" sleep (i.e., entire computer is off) will force all devices into D3<sub>cold</sub>, this isn't true for S3 "suspend" sleep. However, [Linux will put the PCIe host ports into D3<sub>hot</sub> on S3 suspend](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit?id=9d26d3a8f1b0c442339a235f9508bdad8af91043), forcing all downstream devices connected to the ports into either D3<sub>hot</sub> (powered) or D3<sub>cold</sub> (unpowered). ([Windows does something similar](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/bringup/firmware-requirements-for-d3cold))

The point of having separate D3<sub>hot</sub> and D3<sub>cold</sub> states is to allow enumerating the device in D3<sub>hot</sub>. But once the host port is set to D3<sub>hot</sub>, communications with downstream devices are completely severed, meaning from a software point of view the downstream devices are in D3<sub>cold</sub> (but not necessarily electrically).

Since one goal of the D3 state is for power savings, optimal power savings would happen when power is shut off. So an optimal implementation of the host port when entering D3 would include removing bus power (i.e., downstream devices electrically enter D3<sub>cold</sub>).

Since I don't have access to any motherboards schematics to verify things myself, I can only guess that motherboards will implement that "optimal" strategy.
But they might also go the cost-saving route and wire the power rails directly to the PSU, in which case electrical D3<sub>cold</sub> is only possible when the PSU is suspended (S4 sleep or deeper).

**TL;DR**: An ideal power-saving implementation will power off PCIe devices and ports on S3 suspend-to-RAM, making it safe to add or remove devices. But a cost-saving implementation might not.

Comment: Inspired me to remove a m.2 nvme in s3 sleep, worked exactly as expected on Windows

Answer (score -1):

A more generic way to look at this is that there are two types of devices: hotplug devices and non-hotplug devices.  Both device types have hardware and software properties that are relevant here.

From a software perspective, it doesn't matter if the device is hotplug or not.  If you remove a device and the operating system does not expect it, Bad Things will happen.  Best case, you have data corruption.  Worst case, the operating system crashes.  Some operating systems have methods to disconnect some devices or put them in a quiescent state that would allow the device to be removed.  Even devices designed to be hotplugged must be shut down in software before they are physically removed.   A few devices (like sound cards for instance) don't have any internal saved state and can probably be removed without shutting them down, but if they are in use at the time, the operating system won't be happy and likely will at least pop up an error.

Similarly, from a software perspective, adding a device requires operating system support.  Worst case, the operating system will ignore new devices.  In some cases, it may be possible to tell the OS to manually probe for added devices.  If the OS has full hotplug support for a device type, it will autodetect it as soon as the device is added and powered up.  Some operating systems have infrastructure specifically to handle automatic initialization of hotplug devices. Note that software hotplug support is generally independent from hardware hotplug support.

From the hardware perspective, adding or removing a device not designed to be hotplugged can be very dangerous.  When physically adding the device, it may be possible to short out power pins, which could damage both the device and the power supply.  Static charge on either device could be transferred during plugin, killing either device.  Data pins could be connected before some power pins, which could allow power to flow through a pin not designed to carry power.  Even if this doesn't occur, data pins could become active before the device is fully initialized, which could damage things.

If a device is designed to be hotplugged, all of the above problems will be mitigated.  This starts with the physical interface being keyed so it can't be plugged in backwards, and physical guides that force pins to be aligned correctly before any electrical contact is made.  A common mitigation strategy that can be easily spotted and identify a device as potentially hotpluggable is that a few pins will be longer than others.  Typically, the ground pin will be longest, so it makes contact first, allowing any static to dissipate safely and ground potentials between the devices to equalize.  Next longest would be a power pin, allowing the device to power up and partially initialize before the data pins make contact.

PCI and its variants has software specifications to allow hotplug, but not all operating systems or device drivers implement this.  While the pci connector has partial hotplug support, it doesn't have enough physical stability to insure that pins are not cross connected as the card is pushed in.  It is probably a Very Bad Idea to try to hotplug PCI devices in general.  However, there is a standard for "external PCI" that should be fully hotpluggable.

Similarly, SATA is designed to be hotpluggable, but most SATA cables are not stable enough on insertion for this to be safe.  Probably, if the cable is inserted gently and evenly, this would work.  However, ESATA fixes this, and hotplug sata disk bays are very common.  These include guide rails to make sure the drive is inserted into the backplane evenly and once inserted, locked in place so it can't slip out.

The old ATA and PS/2 keyboard and mouse connectors were originally not designed to be hotplugged, but people do it anyway.  Some motherboards don't like this and will break.  Nothing recent has this issue.

RS232 serial doesn't have any of the physical mitigations for hoplug other than a sturdy connector, but electrically it is designed to handle it with no issues.  From a software perspective, serial is a simple protocol, and designed to handle noise and interruption anyway, so there are no additional special software provisions needed.

USB was designed to be fully hotpluggable, and (with a few exceptions of badly designed ports), is safe to hotplug without paying a lot of attention to it.  If you really try hard, you might be able to plug a usb in backwards and physically break something, but with USB C, even that is fixed.  But if you yank out a usb storage device without telling the OS to eject it, you are still likely to corrupt something, even with USB C.

Comment: Does this answer — which is massively long — really add anything new and useful to the specific question? The general gist of the original question was simply asking if it would be safe to swap parts in a PC if the system was suspended to RAM. Reviewing each connection protocol and method doesn’t add much: Unless the PC is designed to have hot swappable items, it doesn’t matter.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the system is suspended to ram or not, it is still a  hotplug issue.  And the question can't really be correctly answered without addressing weather a specific device is hotplug capable or not.  And *every* computer since 1960 has *some* component that is designed to be hotplugged.   Also, I didn't address every component, just tried to give a few cases that were different.

Comment: I agree this is massively long.  But it's a complex issue.  And I felt it was specifically necessary to fully address PCI and disks, since those were specifically mentioned in the question.